# How to bind the resultset value in postgresql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm doing JDBC via PostgreSQL and trying to select the data from the table and displaying it in Webpage.

Here is my code

```
 Connection con = null;
 con = DBHelper.getDBConnection(DBHelper.DBTypes.Postgres);
 java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
 PreparedStatement prepstmt = null;
 String result = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 try {


        final String query = "SELECT distinct area from propertydetails where CAST(area AS text) like '"
                + objBean.getArea()
                + "%' order by area";

        System.out.println("query executed");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            result = getAreaList(rs.getInt(1));

        }


        return result=getAreaList(rs.getInt(1));


 private String getAreaList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, JSONException {
    try {
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
        if (!rs.next()) {
            jarr.put("Sorry, no suggestion found");             
            return CommonHelper.getSuccessMsg(2, jarr);

        } else {
            rs.beforeFirst();               
            while (rs.next()) {
                jarr.put(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("area")));
            }
            return CommonHelper.getSuccessMsg(1, jarr);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return CommonHelper.getErrorMsg();
    } finally {
        rs.close();
    }

}
```

The data is not showing at webpage. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also look at prepared statements. Don't use String concatenation. It is a bad practice.

Comment: I think, you need to put your `result` in a `List` and return the `List`. Line `return result=getAreaList(rs.getInt(1));` outside `while` loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: can u give me example

Comment: I would assume, that it somehow extracts an area list from the `area` field in the database. I for one don't know how java outputs to the webpage (depends on the framework). So if you don't see the "query executed" as output on the webpage, then `System.out.println` is not the right way to do it. Otherwise your query might just return no results. However, do you have any Exceptions thrown?

Comment: that system.out is for my understand only.I am retuning result at the end of the fucntion

Comment: Why do you make an assignment in your `return` statement? Do you understand anything about that code, or are you just trying things randomly and hoping it would work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to yout result in a ArrayList then this list is passed in your getAreaList().
I'm trying write Example pseudo code:
//Declare

```
 ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

//loop

```
while(){
list.add(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

//call getAreaList

```
getAreaList(list);
```

//Your getAreaList() look like

```
public string getAreaList(ArrayList areaList){
//travser one by one elements and do operation which you want..
}
```